# How can I get children in nested documents with some conditions?

Tags: mongodb, nested-documents

I have a collection :

```
{
    _id : ...
    children : [
        {
            code:0
        },

        {
            code:1
        },

        {
            code:2
        }
    ]
},

{
    _id : ...
    children : [
        {
            code:3
        },

        {
            code:4
        },

        {
            code:5
        }
    ]
},

{
    _id : ...
    children : [
        {
            code:6
        },

        {
            code:7
        },

        {
            code:8
        }
    ]
}
```

In this collection, I wanna get children width some code.

For example, if I want children coded 1, 4, 6, the result I need is:

```
{
    code:1
},

{
    code:4
},

{
    code:6
}
```

Every document has some children. Every child has a attribute **code**. How can I do this for this achievement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try it

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([
  {$unwind : "$children"},
  {$match : {"children.code": {$in :[1,4,6]}}},
  {$project : {_id:0, code : "$children.code"}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query always returns a document, so you might not get the very specific result you need, you can search by the children code but ultimately the result will be a collection of document with children attribute.

However this can be achieved by aggregation

```
db.test.aggregate([{$unwind : "$children"},{$match : {$or:[{'children.code':1},
{'children.code':4},{'children.code':6}]}},{$project : {_id:0, code : "$children.code"}}]);
```

Not sure about the syntax but basic idea remain same.

Comment: add  a closing `}` at the end `$match`